# Oracle VirtualBox installation failed on BigSur M1 Apple laptop

Tags: install, virtualbox, apple-silicon

I am trying to install Oracle VirtualBox on Big Sur M1 Apple laptop. Installation failed both on full security and semi-security. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "full security" and "semi-security"?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#hostossupport) states the Mac must be Intel based.

VMware Fusion also has a [free Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal), but [does not yet run on M1, Apple Silicon, ARM  Macs](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005196).

Parallels has a [Technical Preview](https://b2b.parallels.com/apple-silicon) which requires an [ARM version of Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEURw.jpg).

Comment: Might be worth adding that, unless the guest OS brings its own x86 emulator/translator, any VM solution will only be able to virtualize ARM environments.

Comment: @nohillside, There are hypervisors for Apple Silicon which combine with QEMU to allow x86, and other, architectures for the guests.

Comment: @Xalorous You can always post an answer describing this in detail.